# Knockout js: can't write value from form inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a script that produces an array of forms, with each form affecting the available options for the next form. The awesome [martin booth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252959/martin-booth) solved the problem of getting the displayed values to update as new forms are added.

however, I have an observable array (defaultSampleRates) that sits outside the forms array, and for the life of me I can't get the form to push items into that array. I've tried declaring it in a dozen different places in a dozen different ways, but it just won't stick.

basically I need the 'Default sample rate' drop-down to show the sample rates that have been selected in the form above (the user must only be able to choose a default sample rate from a displayed one, rather than from the full list).

Any tips much helpo brain pain. fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3lliot/9vsa4hh7/

html:

```
<body>
    <div style="float:left; width:60%">
        <div data-bind="foreach: forms">
            <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px"> <span> 

            <!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

            <p><span style="color:#AB0002">Sample rate element <span data-bind="text: formNum"></span></span>
                </p>
                <p>Sample rate (Hz):
                    <select data-bind="options: sampleRates, value: selectedSampleRate"></select>
                </p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; clear:both; margin-bottom:20px">
            <hr/>
            <button data-bind="click: addForm">Add &lt;srate&gt; element</button>
            <button data-bind="click: removeForm">Remove</button>
            <p>Default sample rate:
                <select data-bind="options: defaultSampleRates, value: selectedDefaultSampleRate"></select>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:38%; overflow:scroll; border-left:thin; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#dfdfdf;padding-left: 1%"> <span class="code">&lt;audio&gt;</span>

        <ul data-bind="foreach: forms">
            <li>
                <!-- render the json --> <span class="code">&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;srate id="<span data-bind="text: formNum"></span>"&gt;
                <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;sample_rate&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedSampleRate"></span>&lt;&#47;sample_rate&gt;
                <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;&#47;srate&gt;</span>
            </li>
        </ul> <span class="code">&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;default_srate&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedDefaultSampleRate"></span>&lt;&#47;default_srate&gt;</span>
        <br/><span class="code">&lt;&#47;audio&gt;</span>

    </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
//window.onload = startKnockout;
window.onload = startKnockout;
var formNum;
var i = -1;
var selectedSampleRates = [];

function Form(allSampleRates, forms) {
    var self = this;
    // Declare observables
    self.selectedSampleRate = ko.observable();
    self.formNum = ko.observable();

    self.sampleRates = ko.computed(function () {
        var formsValue = forms(),
            availableSampleRates = ko.utils.arrayFilter(allSampleRates, function (sampleRate) {
                return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(formsValue, function (form) {
                    if (form != self) {
                        if (form.selectedSampleRate() === sampleRate) {
                            if (selectedSampleRates.indexOf(sampleRate) === -1) {
                                selectedSampleRates.push(sampleRate);
                            }
                        }

                        return form.selectedSampleRate() === sampleRate;
                    } else {
                        return form != self;
                    }
                });
            });
        return availableSampleRates;
    });

    // count how many srate elements there are 
    i++;
    self.formNum = i;
}

var Vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    var item = 0,
        allSampleRates = ['192000', '176400', '96000', '88200', '48000', '44100'];
    // declare observables for options outside the srate elements   
    self.selectedDefaultSampleRate = ko.observable();

    // add remove forms stuff
    self.forms = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.forms.push(new Form(allSampleRates, self.forms));
    item++;
    self.addForm = function () {
        if (i < 5) {
            self.forms.push(new Form(allSampleRates, self.forms));
            item++;

        } else {
            alert("Can't have more than 6 <srate> elements!")
        }
    };
    self.removeForm = function () {
        if (item > 1) {
            self.forms.splice(item - 1, 1);
            item--;
            i--;
        } else {
            alert("Must have at least one <srate> element!")
        }
    };
    // define arrays for options outside srate elements
    self.defaultSampleRates = ko.observableArray([]);
    return self;
}

// Activates knockout.js
    function startKnockout() {
        ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
    };
```

Comment: Hey, man I was just going through your code, and I noticed something that maybe of use, add this data-bind to your add form button `<button data-bind="click: addForm, disable: forms().length > 5">Add &lt;srate&gt; element</button>`, it will disable the button so you don't have the ability to add more than the required forms

Comment: The same for the remove button, `<button data-bind="click: removeForm, disable: forms().length < 2">Remove</button>` just works better IMHO

Comment: If you are using the above methods then you should be able to get rid of those `i` and `item` variables, you shouldnt really be tracking that in your view model, let knockout do it!

Comment: ok thanks, I'll give that a try when I'm back in the office.

Comment: I rewrote your code, to try and utilize knockout more, and reduce you viewmodel size, I have done it, but there is only one problem! I will post a jsfiddle at some point on monday, and you can see whether you want to do something like that?

Comment: those buttons are much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `selectedOptions` binding to add defaultSample rate.

I changed select `sampleRates` code to this

```
<select data-bind="options: sampleRates, value: selectedSampleRate, selectedOptions: $root.defaultSampleRates"></select>
```

Notice `selectedOptions` binding there..

Should work as per your need.

***Updated*** Fiddle Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/9vsa4hh7/3/

I hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: thanks - that's my original fiddle though. I tried changing the select to your code above but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry.. I gave you wrong link :-| I will update it asap

Comment: @ElliotSumner I have edited the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/9vsa4hh7/2/

Comment: sorry, I think you've misunderstood the requirement, maybe I wasn't clear. the 'default sample rate' drop-down needs to include all sample rates that are currently selected in however many forms are displayed. so for example, if you have one form with '192000' selected as the sample rate and one form with '176400' as the selected sample rate, the default sample rate drop-down needs to include those 2 values. also I think there is something wrong with the code now, it is not rendering properly in the right-hand div.

Comment: @ElliotSumner I have edited an answer for you.. New JSFIddle. I think you should create remove button for individual form instead of one global. That's just a suggestion.. http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/9vsa4hh7/3/

Comment: thanks again - the 'default sample rate' drop-down doesn't work though.

Comment: that's nearly there, but it doesn't add the sample rate to the 'default sample rate' drop-down until you select a new sample rate from the form at the top.

Comment: Ok, do you want the value to be pushed in when page is loaded?